# Convert CSV to TSV

Tags: linux, csv, sed

How do you convert this csv file into a tab delimited file?

```
"Country","Percent","Percent of patients","home health","home health agency","friends and family","Surveys","Response"
"Nation","88","85","83","84","78",,
```

Notice both the Surverys and Response columns are empty strings.

I use this code to convert it to a tab file -

```
sed 's/\"\,\"/\"\t\"/g'
sed 's/\,\,/\t""\t/g'
```

It doesn't convert the last column though. This is the output I get (Notice the last column is omitted) -

```
"Country"   "Percent"   "Percent of patients"   "home health"   "home health agency"    "friends and family"    "Surveys"   "Response"
"Nation"        "88"    "85"    "83"    "84"    "78"    ""
```

There are 8 columns in the header and only 7 columns in the tab delimited data, so the last column is missed.

**UPDATE**

My column names have commas in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\",\""; OFS="\t"} {FS=","; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/"/,"",$i); $i="\"" $i "\""} print}' file
```

Output:

```
"Country"      "Percent"       "Percent of patients"   "home health"   "home health agency"    "friends and family"       "Surveys"       "Response"
"Nation"        "88"    "85"    "83"    "84"    "78"    ""      ""
```

Comment: My headers have a comma in them, so this is not working for that.

Comment: Could it be that this important information is missing in your question?

Comment: Added to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your last column is not missing at all. You just don't see it because it's a tab. You can check it with `xxd`.

Also, you don't need to escape commas and double-quotes in sed since you have everything inside single quotes.

```
sed 's/","/"\t"/g; s/,,/\t""\t/g;' $YOUR_CSV | xxd | tail -1.
```

This shows that the last line ends with a tab (`x09`) after the last quote and before the ending newline :

```
00000090: 3834 2209 2237 3822 0922 2209 0a         84"."78".""..
```

What is "missing" is the double-quotes around that last empty value. But you don't need them. If you really want these double-quotes, you can add this to your sed command:

```
s/\t$/\t""/
```

It will replace a tab at the end of a line with a tab followed by 2 double-quotes.

However, this simple `sed` substitution can of course easily fail depending on your data.

For example (using `-` instead of `\t` for visibility), if you have empty columns which are not at the end:

```
echo '"Nation","88",,,"84","78",,' | sed 's/","/"-"/g; s/,,/-""-/g;'
```

Will output

```
"Nation"-"88"-""-,"84"-"78"-""-
```

(notice the comma before "84")

So I would suggest using a dedicated tool rather than a quick sed line. For example, `csvtool` is available in most distributions (`sudo apt install csvtool` for Debian based).

```
csvtool -t COMMA -u TAB cat $YOUR_CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

I do use `FPAT` with `gnu awk` to handle CSV files

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
"Country"       "Percent"       "Percent of patients"   "home health"   "home health agency"    "friends and family"    "Surveys"       "Response"
"Nation"        "88"    "85"    "83"    "84"    "78"
```

Not sure what you mean by last column is missing.  If its empty `,,` you will not see it.

Comment: I mean there are 8 columns in the header and only 7 columns in the tab delimited data, so the last column is missed.

Comment: @Aaron Still not understand.  What would output do you like to get for the missing column?  A blank space?  A star? Get data from some other places?